# Estructura BBDD para tareas de diferente tipo SQL

Tags: sql

Quiero realizar un registro de Tareas. Existen 4 tipos de SUBTAREAS, cada una con sus características propias. Son características comunes a todas ellas:

```
Tener una fecha de inicio
Tener una fecha de fin
Tener un indicador del tipo de tarea
Tener un indicador de la federación que propone dicha tarea.
```

Los 4 tipos de tarea que existen son:

```
Tareas de test
Tareas de vídeo
Tareas de archivo
Tareas de encuesta
```

Las tareas de Test consisten en "Realizar X test, de los cuales Y deben superar una nota Z". Para esta tarea no se registrará ningún tipo de respuesta. Simplemente comparando tabla TestFinalizado(Id,Usuario,Nota,Fecha), mediante php se comprobará el número de tests y las notas que se han obtenido en el lapso de tiempo indicado la tarea.

En las tareas de Vídeo, un formador propondrá un enlace a un vídeo el cual hay que analizar y dar una respuesta reglamentaria, dividida en Sanción Técnica y Sanción Disciplinaria. Además, se dará también un enlace a un vídeo con la solución, el cual estará disponible una vez que cumpla el plazo de la tarea. En este momento ya no se podrán enviar más respuestas.

En las tareas de Archivo, un formador subirá un documento PDF con unos requisitos o unas directrices. Como respuesta a este documento, cada árbitro tendrá que subir otro archivo que cumpla los requisitos que se piden en el PDF del formador (pueden pedir otro pdf, una foto, un vídeo, etc.). A este también se podrá proponer una solución que estará disponible en el momento en el que cumpla el plazo de la tarea.

En las tareas de Encuesta, un formador podrá realizar una pregunta y proponer hasta 5 posibles respuestas. Además, podrá elegir si las respuestas son de opción única o multi-opción. Además, se podrá definir un texto como solución a la pregunta de la encuesta, que estará disponible en el momento en el que cumpla el plazo de la tarea.

Mi idea es implementarlo con las siguientes tablas y relaciones:

[image: tablas y relaciones]

Pero no estoy muy seguro de si esta sería la forma correcta. El resto de tablas de la base de datos están apiladas en la esquina superior izquierda. Esas tablas no son importantes en este momento, por eso las escondo.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Hola he estado echando un vistazo a tu planteamiento y si no creo mal, todas las tareas heredan(están relacionadas) con tarea con sus claves foráneas, hasta ahí todo correcto y después cada tarea independiente esta unida a su respuesta. Lo único que no se es si Tarea debería estar relacionada a usuario en plan cada usuario tiene N tareas.

Comment: Es decir. Conectar Tarea directamente con Usuario en lugar de conectar las diferentes subtareas? Si, quizá pueda ser mejor opción.

Comment: Bueno lo he estado revisando y es mejor como está para el planteamiento que quiero realizar. Gracias de todas formas